# Detect browser (tab) closing or reloading on Vue

Tags: vue.js, ipad, page-refresh, onbeforeunload

I am currently using window.onbeforeunload function on my vue to detect browser's closing or reloading tab to show a  like below.

```
  mounted: function () {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.confirmSave)
  },
   methods: {
    confirmSave(event) {
      if (this.onChangeMode) {
        event.returnValue = 'You have some unsaved changes'
        return 'You have some unsaved changes'
      }
    },
  },
```

It's working perfectly on PC Chrome but not working on iPad (both Safari and Chrome). My iPad version is 14.0.1.
I also tried something else like pagehide but not working either.

Comment: This is entirely my guess.

First of all, Safari on iOS does not support the main action of the beforeunload event. (String assignment and string return) Safari's engine uses WebKit engine, and iOS's Chrome uses WebKit engine as well, so from the same point of view, it can be seen that it is not supported.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any solution for that?